# Pushing two divs behind logo

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS. But this thing is getting on my nerves. I have tried everything to solve this thing but unable to do so. I am practicing with a sample website.

Main issue i Am trying to apply this logo which I marked under a rectangle above two ".divs". Sorry I am newbie and don't know how to properly. I am attaching my coding below of css.
 I need to put those two divs below this image.

[image]

I am newbie so don't know how to paste code. This thing is new for. please any help would be appreciated. [enter link description here](http://pastebin.com/eHN7cHKJ)

Comment: could you please create a snippet / fiddle so that we can check?

Comment: sorry i dont know how to do that. I have pasted the PASTEBIN LINK. you can check that out . I didn't know how to paste code here. you can click on "enter the link description here"

Comment: Dude create a free account on here https://codepen.io/ and then paste your stuff and link it, there is loads of markup going on here that shouldn't be in there, its unneeded

Comment: @Ricky https://codepen.io/sachoosaini/pen/pEozqo

Comment: If i have answered your question can you mark it as complete please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Well its hard to see without the images actually being included on the codepen.

I've gone through your code and eliminated the syntax errors/spelling mistakes etc and made it abit cleaner, so hopefully it will work for you, if not if you can provide images on the codepen it would make it alot easier.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="image">
    </div>

<div id="wrapper">

<header>
    <div class="headerbox1"></div>
</header>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="headerbox2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background:#BCBCBC;
    }
#wrapper {
         height:2278px;
         width:1600px;
         background:#ABFF7E;
         margin: 0 auto;
        }
header{
         width:1600px;
         height:57px;
         background:#FF1D21;
         margin: 0 auto;
      }
.headerbox1{
           width:1600px;
           height:57px;
           background:#EDE8E9;
           margin: 0 auto;
       }
        }
.banner{
             width:1600px;
             height:559px;
             background:url(../../Images/alpha.jpg);
         }
.headerbox2{
            width:1600px;
            height:63px;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
.image {
              width:219px;
              height:185px;
              background:url(../../Images/logo%20spotless.png);
              display: inline-block;
              margin: 0 auto;
          }
```

I could see no relevant reason for you to use the `<td>` tags in your html, especially as you don't have a table in there, so i have took them out.
Hope this helps, If not your need to provide images aswell.

Comment: (http://pasteboard.co/fx8adR4sw.png) main image the logo above need to be pasted on the top of the two like i pasted in the question of the topmost post.

attaching other images
http://pasteboard.co/fxb8NK08i.jpg

logo 
http://pasteboard.co/1yjM4BhxQ.png

and the TD's i just added to adjust the image above the two divs.

Comment: Have a look at the code now, You added the logo twice, once in the HTML and then again as a background image for a div class that was not defined, I took out the HTML img and created a div in it's place using the class attribute you had styled in but had no div for, and placed it above the wrapper so it should align in the center.

Comment: i think i still not able to make u understand what i want. i want to place those header divs beneath the LOGO i mean the logo png.if you look original page u can see the logo spotless is above two divs which in my case are header divs

Comment: I understand what it is you want, Bringing the LOGO above everything else, and setting it into the centre of the page. So effectively bringing the image div above the wrapper, will bring it above everything else (ON TOP) and then setting margin: 0 auto; should centre it on the page exactly where you want it.